# Find Directory and Convert containing files

Tags: terminal, find, imagemagick

I am trying to Find directories recursively any sub directories named "Dev" from a top folder and copy & resize the images to a different directory. So far, this works for copying:

```
find . -name 'dev' -type d -exec cp -r "{}" /mnt/IMAGES2023/IMAGES2023/senior-collect \;
```

but just copies, and not downsizes. I would like to downsize as it copies with imagemagick Convert. So far I have tried a bunch and pretty close with:

```
find . -name 'Dev' -type d -exec for f in * ; do convert $f -resize 300x300 /Volumes/IMAGES2023/IMAGES2023/senior-collect/$f ; done
```

However it throws Parse errors. Any help is Greatly appreciated.

```
find . -name 'Dev' -type d -exec for f in * ; do convert $f -resize 300x300 /Volumes/IMAGES2023/IMAGES2023/senior-collect/$f ; done
```

to find any sub directory named "Dev" and copy & resize the images to a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a command more like this:

```
find . -name Dev -type d -exec bash -c 'cd {} && for f in *; do magick "$f" -resize 64x48 /Volumes/IMAGES2023/IMAGES2023/senior-collect/"$f"; done' \;
```